# Understanding what appears to be an example of destructuring in clojure

Tags: clojure

The following code:

```
(into {} [[:a 1][:b 2][:c 3][:d 4][:e 5]])
```

...produces a map(?) of keyword / value pairs. I don't quite understand the significance of the double square brackets and I am assuming it is an example of destructuring?

Thanks,

~Caitlin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a [destructuring](http://john2x.com/blog/clojure-destructuring/), it's just an example of using [`into` core function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into).

`into` is a function used to conjoin two collection by repeatedly adding elements from the second collection to the first one with [`conj` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj).

So, `(into {} [[:a 1][:b 2]])` is just a synonym for

```
(-> {} (conj [:a 1]) (conj [:b 2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a supplement to Leonid's.  One can think of a Clojure map as a collection of "map entries", key/value pairs.  These are sometimes printed so that they look like 2-element vectors, though they are not 2-element vectors.  Nevertheless, if you want to convert something into a map using `into`, it makes sense that you should pass the data that will turn into map entries in the form of 2-element vectors.

```
=> (def foo {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
#'/foo
=> (find foo :b)
[:b 2]
=> (class (find foo :b))
clojure.lang.MapEntry
=> (map identity foo)
([:c 3] [:b 2] [:a 1])
=> (map class (map identity foo))
(clojure.lang.MapEntry clojure.lang.MapEntry clojure.lang.MapEntry)
=> (list [:c 3] [:b 2] [:a 1])
([:c 3] [:b 2] [:a 1])
=> (map class (list [:c 3] [:b 2] [:a 1]))
(clojure.lang.PersistentVector clojure.lang.PersistentVector clojure.lang.PersistentVector)
```

Comment: map entries are a type of vector, and into being used to populate a map will fail if the inputs are not already vectors of some sort

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I didn't realize that.  I wondered why I couldn't convert lists directly into map entries using `into`.

Comment: easy to demonstrate: `(vector? (first {:a 0}))
`